# Strange string output

Tags: c, string, undefined-behavior

I am learning C and I don't understand the output I get when printing the string myString after the calls to functions ayInFrontOfConsonant() and replaceChars(). The goal of this stage of the exercise is that the user can input a string. The string should then be printed like this: all lower case vowels should be replaced with the letter 'a' and in front of each word that starts with a consonant the letter "ay" should be added. When I enter the string "I like writing C code" the output should be: "I aylaka aywrating ayC aycada". I am getting this output however at the end of this string I am getting some strange symbols. It is like it is the 72 characters of the string and some of these characters are random in memory.

I would really appreciate any help you can provide.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void insertChar(char *str, char aChar, int index)
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=strlen(str);i>=index;i--)          //sizeof of strlen???
    {
        str[i]=str[i-1];
    }
    str[index]=aChar;
}


void ayInFrontOfConsonant(char *str)
{
    char *consonants="bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";
    int i=0,j=0;
    for ( i = 0;i<strlen(str) ; i++)                 
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < strlen(consonants); j++)
        {
            if (str[i] == consonants[j] && i==0)       
            {
                insertChar(str, 'y', i);
                insertChar(str,'a',i);
                break;
            }
            else if(i!=0 && str[i-1]==' ' && str[i] == consonants[j])    
            {
                printf("i=%d\n",i);
                insertChar(str, 'y', i);
                insertChar(str,'a',i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int replaceChars(char str[], char sChar[], char rChar)
{
    int cnt=0,i=0,j=0;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<strlen(sChar);j++)
        {
            if(str[i]==sChar[j])
            {
                str[i]=rChar;
                cnt++;
            }
        }
    }
    return cnt;
}


int main()
{
    printf("** Welcome to the Double Dutch game **\n");
    char myString[72];
    printf("Please enter a string: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", myString);
    replaceChars(myString, "eiou", 'a');
    ayInFrontOfConsonant(myString);
    printf("Double dutch traslation: %s\n",myString);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sounds like your string isn't `NUL` terminated. Try changing to `char myString[72] = { 0 };` This will initialize all members of the array to 0 (the `NUL` string terminator in `c`),, and assuming your functions are working correctly and not overwriting the bounds of the array minus 1, there should be at least one 0 left in the array. `printf` will keep on printing until it finds a `\0`.

Comment: NUL terminator missing, at a guess.  Nearly always is.

Comment: Thankyou SO much guys it works!

Comment: One real suggestion: why are you trying to do string-intensive operations with the one popular language least suited to the job, if not to torture yourself?

Comment: Note `s` servess no useful purpose in the format.   Suggest `scanf("%71[^\n]", myString);`  Add width, drop s

Comment: The `char myString[72] = { 0 };` idea will work for output that is 71 characters or less.  Yet long input could cause the output to attempt to form a string exceeding 71+1 (for the null character).  Pre-filling an array with zero is not fundamentally addressing the issue of appending a null character and insuring that the array is not overrun.